# Window resizing causes misalignment of elements on scroll animation that uses requestAnimationFrame

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-plugins, window-resize, requestanimationframe

I’m using jquery.parallax-scroll.js (J.P-S) which relies on window.requestAnimationFrame to do scrolling animations.
My script animates movement of an element on both x and y axis while scrolling to reach and overlap a target element located somewhere down the page.

It works great as long as the window in not resized.
When the window is resized, the position for both elements change but the coordinates for the already-on-going animation do not and that causes the moving element to no longer overlap the target when scrolling to it (a misalignment).
Refreshing the page after resizing corrects the misalignment but that is not an acceptable solution for obvious reasons.

Using $(window).on('resize', handler), I’m able — on resize — to update the “data-parallax“ attributes of the animated element in the DOM.
These are the controlling attributes that provide J.P-S with the starting and ending coordinates as well as the distance to travel.
However, I have not been able to restart the animation with updated coordinates.
J.P-S is indeed loaded when the document is ready.
My thoughts are that if I could get the J.P-S script to restart after the “data-“ attributes are updated using a window on resize event, a new animation would be rendered with the new updated coordinates and the misalignment would be corrected…
That may or may not be the right approach but I’m running out of ideas… J.P-S has a very limited API with no event hooks besides the initial call…

A minimal, complete and verifiable example is located at https://codepen.io/decam/pen/daKeyj. See snippet bellow as well.

jquery.parallax-scroll.js is located at https://github.com/alumbo/jquery.parallax-scroll.

How can I correct the misalignment caused by window resizing without reloading the page?

```js
'use strict';

$(function() {
  ScrollAnimations.init();
});

let ScrollAnimations = {
  init: function() {
    this.setAnimations();
  },

  setAnimations: function() {
    setDataPararllax();

    function setDataPararllax() {
      // Get the bullet element's top and left
      // coordinates from declared CSS
      let $bullet = $('#bullet');
      let bullet_top = parseFloat($bullet.css('top'));
      let bullet_left = parseFloat($bullet.css('left'));

      // Get the target element's relative top and
      // left coordinates
      let $target = $('#target');
      let target_top = $target.position().top;
      let target_left = $target.position().left;

      // Calculate x and y distance offsets
      let x_distance = target_left - bullet_left;
      let y_distance = target_top - bullet_top;

      // Prepare JSON objects with the controlling parameters
      // required by the jquery-Parallax-Scrolling.js script
      // to be added as data- attributes of the bullet element
      let data_consts = `"from-scroll": ${bullet_top}, "to-scroll": ${target_top - bullet_top}, "smoothness": 10`;
      let data_p_y = `{"y": ${y_distance}, ${data_consts}}`;
      let data_p_x = `{"x": ${x_distance}, ${data_consts}}`;

      // Add the data- attributes to the bullet element
      $bullet.attr({
        'data-parallax': data_p_y,
        'data-parallax2': data_p_x
      });
    }
  }
};
```

```css
html,
body,
.panel {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: #96b38a;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
}


/* Set bullet absolute position to any
  value using top and left properties */

#bullet {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50vh;
  left: 75vw;
}

#top {
  height: 120vh;
  background-color: #333333;
  text-align: center;
}

#bottom {
  height: 250vh;
  background-color: #666666;
}

.panel {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

span {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #ddca7e;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
  <title>Scroll Bullet->Target Animation</title>
</head>

<body>
  <svg id="bullet" height="10" width="10">
      <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="5" fill="white" />
    </svg>
  <div id="top" class="panel">
    <p><span>Scroll down...</span><br> Window resizing is NOT yet supported...<br> If white bullet doesn't overlap the black target after scrolling,<br>you've resized the window...<br> Refresh the browser and try again.<br> I'm currently working on a solution...
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="bottom" class="panel">
    <svg id="target" height="10" width="10">
        <rect width="10" height="10" fill="black" />
      </svg>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alumbo/jquery.parallax-scroll/js/jquery.parallax-scroll.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution and I’m answering my own question in case anyone else runs into something similar in the future.

The J.P-S script works by animating the DOM element’s style based on the JSON settings passed thru the data-parallax attributes.
The script adds the style attribute with the animations.

To make elements (and their animations) realign when the window is resized, I call a function on a windows resize event to replace the data-parallax attributes.
I remove the entire data-parallax and style attributes from the DOM element, not just their values and attach new data attributes with another name and the new values.
Using a counter, I create and attach new data- attributes. E.g. data-1parallax for the first resize event, data-2parallax for the second and so on.
Then I call a small function I added to the J.P-S script that replaces the data- attribute names the script uses to get the parameters and animate the element.
That name is replaced with the matching name generated on the resizing event (I pass the counter value);
Obviously, I’ve made the data- attribute name in the script a variable.

As a result, I end up with new data-[#]parallax attributes with JSON values calculated after resize (previous data-[#]parallax attributes were deleted) and then the script generates a new style attribute with the correct values.
Debouncing the event ensures I only run this process once per user resizing of the window.
If anyone needs more clarification or code, please post a comment and I’ll provide.

I have updated the CodePen with a corrected version and you can demo the resizable script there. See link to CodePen inside the question.